# Add new updates on Android App

Tags: android

I am a beginner on Android as I am working on developing a new Android app. In my project I have some problems when the user click on an icon, it should redirect him to dot net website I did in my code.

1. If I want to update the apk file on customer mobile to update it should prompt to the user to download the new version. How can I achieve this?
2. Also how can I know this app belong me between many app on customer device?
3. I want to fetch the bugs and errors that may occurred on the customer device. How can I do it?

Comment: user1644081 you can accept an answer if you satisfied with one. otherwise give feedback what you like to do or what you wish.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Better to implement GCM push service in your application to send a notification about the update to all your application users.

http://developer.android.com/guide/google/gcm/index.html

This framework will give your application to support push notify the user from your server, and what you need to do in your application just track the received push and write a code to download new APk from server and install it automatically.

The second thing you asked about the Crash reports so the best option is use [ACRA](http://code.google.com/p/acra/wiki/BasicSetup) technology to get the your application report on server everything force close or logcat

Both are very easy to implement so enjoy!!

Answer (score 3):

1. 2.

If you release your app in the Google Play Store the updates are managed automatically by Google. You can just release another version of the app in the Google Play Store and all users will be notified from Google that a new version is available.

3.

If you release your app in the Google Play Store bugs will be reported automatically by Google to your Google-Mail Account.

Answer (score 0):

At first use [GCM](http://developer.android.com/guide/google/gcm/index.html) for push notifications like updates for your application.
Second use[Google Analytics for any bug report crashes usage](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/android/resources)