# Android app how to keep updated

Tags: c#, android, xamarin.android

I'm developing an App with MonoForAndroid, the app is almost finished, but I have a doubt.
Once I install the app on a tablet, if I need to make changes to the app how can I update the tablet with the new changes? Do I need to connect the tablet to the computer by USB and do it manually? Can it can be done programatically, by ftp or something?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: May this is helpful to you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12262047/add-new-updates-on-android-app/12262248#12262248

Comment: Use one of the many Android Application Stores that exists.  I don't believe you will be able to update it like one might update a normal PC application.  While you can side-load an application on Android there are still security concerns allowing an application to update itself.

Comment: I'm guessing you are not trying to put your app on google play yet, you may be just releasing the app to the device to test, I develop on monodroid to and I usually just connect the tablet for releasing. Anyway you could use something like [Wondershare Mobilego](http://www.wondershare.com/android-manager/) to transfer the apk to te device, I hope this helps.

Comment: How can I used an Android Application Stores, sorry for my ignorance, Im new in Android. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

If you are using Google Play, the updates are done automatically. You dont have to worry about it.

Comment: But the user is responsible for activating the update. Maybe @ramo2712 wants it automaticly.

Comment: Yes I want it automatically, and I not using Google Play. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
And to show the update notification to the user,use GCM Service.

      <http://developer.android.com/guide/google/gcm/gcm.html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You may serve it from some HTTP-Server , provided it usesproper mime type (recent versions of apache httpd do it out of the box)  browser will prompt you to reinstall on hitting  link.

Comment: How I do that? Do you have a sample or a link to documentation? Thnaks

Comment: just place APK into directory served by webserver  and hit link to it in browser. Like this:  http://www.pribluda.de/android/lines/  ( use direct download ) - should work from your tablet